# How to write a function that is the sum of all $y$ values at some $x$ value of a relation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, polynomials, graphing-functions

For example, if I had the relation: $x^3 + 3x^2 + y^3 - y^2 - 15y + 20 = 0$, and I wanted to find the sum of all $y$ values at $x=1$.

So if my new function was $f(x)$, then $f(1)$ would be about
$3.5 + 1.7 + (-4) = 1.2$.
How would I write such a function on desmos?

[image]

Maybe I could simplify and rewrite the relation, but that might not work for other relations.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** At $x=1$, the $y$ values are roots of the equation

$$1 +3 +y^3-y^2-15y+20=0.$$

Hence, what are the sum of the roots?

> Apply Vieta's formula.

Note:

- This only works directly because we have 3 real roots.
  Or alternatively, if you wanted to sum all real+complex roots.
- The explicit roots when $ x = 1$ are $\approx -4.09, 1.75, 3.33$ which have a sum that's much closer to 1 instead of the 1.2 that you calculated from eyeballing it.

Comment: is there no general way? For example, what if my relation was $x^{3}+3x^{2}+y^{3}-y^{2}-15y+20+5sin(x)-3tan(y)=0$

Comment: @WillKanga No there is not. This is a unique property of one-variable polynomials. EG Even the one-variable equation $ 0 = \sin x $ has infinitely many solutions, and has no sum (in the standard infinite sum interpretation).